# I can't able to go to previous page on Webview and OnBackPressed() is not working in my WebView Activity

Tags: android, webview

This is my code for WebActivity. I'm having two Activities->Resource activity and webActivity. I'm passing the URL from Resource Activity to WebActivity.Please guide me in which Activity I should put that code i.e Resource Activity or Web Activity??

```
public class WebActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private WebView mwebview;
private ProgressDialog progressBar;

protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    final WebView mwebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = mwebview.getSettings();
    mwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String uri = getIntent().getExtras().getString("uri");

    mwebview.loadUrl(uri);

    String auri = getIntent().getExtras().getString("auri");
    mwebview.loadUrl(auri);
    String huri = getIntent().getExtras().getString("huri");
    mwebview.loadUrl(huri);
    String eouri = getIntent().getExtras().getString("eouri");
    mwebview.loadUrl(eouri);
    String houri = getIntent().getExtras().getString("houri");
    mwebview.loadUrl(houri);
    String bouri = getIntent().getExtras().getString("bouri");
    mwebview.loadUrl(bouri);





    }
//My OnBackPressed Code 

@Override
 public void onBackPressed() 
 {
 if (mwebview.canGoBack())
  mwebview.goBack();
  else
  super.onBackPressed();

}




}
```

Comment: You are supposed to add it into Activity class, add @Override on method so you know you are overriding the correct one.

Comment: debug if mwebview.canGoBack() is returning false

Comment: why are you loading all urls at once?

Comment: I'm not loading all at once. Those are Intents.